# Using requestAnimationFrame as a Timer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr

This is a multi-player "guess the word" turn-based game I am working on.

I have a page that is supposed to count down from a given number. If a word-guess is submitted before the time limit, a SignalR hub method is called. If 0 is reached, a different SignalR hub method is called. In both cases, the hub method sends a message back out to all relevant clients (in a group).

Someone recommended, instead of a JS timer, I can use requestAnimationFrame which updates every 17 milliseconds.

So here is what requestAnimationFrame code I have in the Play.aspx file...

```
function turnTimerOn() { //called by server code as a startup script

      var timerStep = '<%=Application(Session("GameID") & "_TimeLimit")%>';
      timerStep = Number(timerStep);

      var startT = Date.now();
      var timedifference = 0;
      var countdown = document.getElementById('SecondsLeft');
      requestAnimationFrame(function anim() {
               requestAnimationFrame(anim);
               startT = startT || Date.now();
               countdown.innerHTML = timerStep - ((Date.now() - startT) / 1000 | 0);
               timedifference = (Date.now() - startT) / 1000 | 0;

               if (timedifference >= timerStep) {

                      startT = Date.now();
                      timedifference = 0;

                      countdown.innerHTML = "";
                      TomatoHubProxy.invoke('NextPlayer', '<%=Session("username")%>', '<%=Session("GameID")%>');
                 } 
           });

     }
```

The return message from the SignalR hub causes execution of turnTimerOn() again, and this is meant to start the countdown again for the current player.

The count down seems to work but has a bug where it reaches a low number like 3 or 4 and then either resets the count down or invokes the Hub method (it's hard to tell what is happening). It is supposed to invoke the Hub method when the count down reaches 0 (so that the game can move to the next player)

I should also mention the Play.aspx page is never re-loaded. All updates happen automatically (thanks to SignalR)

Please help.

Comment: I think I have identified the problem - the requestAnimationFrame is persisting after 0 has been reached. So I need to stop it in this statement:

if (timedifference >= timerStep) {  any one know how to do this?

Comment: move the requestAnimationFrame(anim); line to after the if (...){...}else{/*here*/}